# Matrix PHP Error: Undefined property: Content_publish::$tools_model

Tags: matrix, pixelandtonic, php-errors, fatal

Opps I know better than to not include this stuff!!

> EE version: 2.5.0
>   Matrix version: 2.2.2.1

I was setting up a new channel and tried to access the entry page for it and got this error. Anyone know how to fix? Or what's happening?

Here is the error.

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: Content_publish::$tools_model
>
> Filename: celltypes/file.php
>
> Line Number: 120
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function get_upload_preferences() on a non-object in /www/******/public_html/*******/expressionengine/third_party/matrix/celltypes/file.php on line 120

Thanks Much!

Comment: Probably a mismatch between your Matrix version and EE version. Post your versions?

Comment: Yep, as Derek said - we need your Matrix and EE version numbers please. :)

Comment: Lucas - I'd definitely recommend upgrading Matrix; you're quite a few versions behind and an upgrade is likely to fix this particular issue.  You may also want to upgrade EE since you're quite a bit behind there as well. :(

Comment: How are you coming along with this, Lucas? Did an upgrade fix it?